# OpenId Connect(OIDC) v2 login_hint on sign-out not working

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, openid-connect

I have noticed that after I started using **OpenId Connect(OIDC) v2** on my .NET Core project, I am being prompted to select an account on sign-out even though I have configured `OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut` to use `LoginHint`.

I couldn't find anything about it in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc). My configuration is:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
      .AddAzureAD(options =>
      {
          Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
      });

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
  {
       options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
       options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "preferred_username";

       // Handling the sign-out
       options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async context =>
       {
           var user = context.HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
           string displayName = user.FindFirstValue("preferred_username");

           // Avoid displaying the select account dialog
           context.ProtocolMessage.LoginHint = displayName;
           context.ProtocolMessage.DomainHint = "organizations";
           await Task.FromResult(0);
        };
   });
```

So, how can I avoid the account selection screen when signing-out using **OIDC v2** on a .NET Core project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to avoid this, this is by design by the AAD service on V2. This V2 behavior is added for additional security by the service team. You can refer to [this github issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/735#issuecomment-508259782) for more details.

Comment: This github issue is related to MSAL.js. I am talking about `Microsoft.Identity.Client` for dotnet

Comment: @TiagoBrenck Logout screen is not controlled by MSAL JS but the service.